# Adding Facebook authentication to devise User model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth-facebook

I have been trying to add facebook authentication to my devise Customer model. While the login link does redirect to the facebook app link, after clicking login it redirects me to my sign up page, and the customer is not persisted in my database at all. Can someone please shed some insight as to why my customers aren't being saved and how I can redirect them to the customer show page? Thanks in advance:

Omniauth.rb:

```
OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, '*********', '**********'
end
```

omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb:

```
class Customers::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

     def facebook
        # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
        @customer = Customer.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

        if @customer.persisted?
          sign_in_and_redirect @customer, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
          set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
        else
          session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
          redirect_to new_customer_registration_url
        end
    end
end
```

Customer.rb file (my model):

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, 
         :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]

  validates :customername, presence: true

  has_many :orders

  has_many :pins, :dependent => :destroy

 def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |customer|
    customer.email = auth.info.email
    customer.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    customer.customername = auth.info.name   # assuming the user model has a name
  end
 end

end
```

Comment: any possible solutions?

Comment: i haven't used devise but don't you need to call save on your customer after pulling the info e.g. `customer.save` so it can save to the database